# persistent checkboxes, dynamic table, php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I've been working on this nonstop and none of the online suggestions have worked.
I have a dynamically created table that refreshes every 5 seconds. There are checkboxes on the table, if you check a box it highlights the row.  When the page refreshes all checked states are lost, I need them to be saved, either by local storage or a cookie or even writing out to a file.
Please help and thanks in advance.

My currently working code that does not retain the checked state:

```
    <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>list</TITLE>
<META name="description" content="">
<META name="keywords" content="">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
    <style>
.inv {
    display: none;
}

table.sortable thead {
    background-color:#999;
    color:#222222;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: default;
}
table.sortable tbody {
    counter-reset: sortabletablescope;
}
table.sortable thead tr::before {
    content: "";
    display: table-cell;
}
table.sortable tbody tr::before {
    content: counter(sortabletablescope);
    counter-increment: sortabletablescope;
    display: table-cell;
}
    </style>
<script src="../../sorttable.js"></script>
<script>
function toggle_highlight(inputTagReference)
{
    var is_checked = inputTagReference.checked; //true or false
    if(is_checked)
    {
        inputTagReference.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    }
    else
    {
        inputTagReference.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="";
    }
}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#dddddd" TEXT="#000000" LINK="#0000FF" VLINK="#800080">
<h1 align="center">List</h1>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">
<?php
    echo '<div>';

    //Create file with headers


system("cmd /C makeit.bat");


    //Create html table
echo '<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>';
echo '<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>';
echo '<table class="sortable" align="center">';

$row = 0;
$handle = fopen("readylist.txt", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($row == 0) {
        // this is the first line of the file
        // it contains titles of columns
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<thead>\n<tr>";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo "<th align='left' height='75' width='135'>" . $data[$c] . "</th>";
        }
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "</tr>\n</thead>\n\n<tbody>";
    } else {
        // this handles the rest of the lines of the file
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<tr id=Row0$row>";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo "<td id=Col0$c>" . $data[$c] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='Chk$row id=Chk$row' value='Chk$row' onclick='toggle_highlight(this)'></td>";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
}
fclose($handle);

echo "</tbody>\n</table>";



echo '</div>';

?>
</p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here it is with nonworking solution:

```
        <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>list</TITLE>
    <META name="description" content="">
    <META name="keywords" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
        <style>
#checkbox-container{
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

#checkbox-container div{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#checkbox-container button{
  margin-top: 5px;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: .5em .6em;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
    .inv {
        display: none;
    }

    table.sortable thead {
        background-color:#999;
        color:#222222;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: default;
    }
    table.sortable tbody {
        counter-reset: sortabletablescope;
    }
    table.sortable thead tr::before {
        content: "";
        display: table-cell;
    }
    table.sortable tbody tr::before {
        content: counter(sortabletablescope);
        counter-increment: sortabletablescope;
        display: table-cell;
    }
        </style>
    <script src="../../sorttable.js"></script>
    <script src="../../jquery.js"></script>
<script>
var formValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formValues')) || {};
var $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");
var $button = $("#checkbox-container button");

function allChecked(){
  return $checkboxes.length === $checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
}

function updateButtonStatus(){
  $button.text(allChecked()? "Uncheck all" : "Check all");
}

function handleButtonClick(){
  $checkboxes.prop("checked", allChecked()? false : true)
}

function updateStorage(){
  $checkboxes.each(function(){
    formValues[this.id] = this.checked;
  });

  formValues["buttonText"] = $button.text();
  localStorage.setItem("formValues", JSON.stringify(formValues));
}

$button.on("click", function() {
  handleButtonClick();
  updateButtonStatus();
  updateStorage();
});

$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
  updateButtonStatus();
  updateStorage();
});

// On page load
$.each(formValues, function(key, value) {
  $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});

$button.text(formValues["buttonText"]);
</script>
    <script>
    function toggle_highlight(inputTagReference)
    {
        var is_checked = inputTagReference.checked; //true or false
        if(is_checked)
        {
            inputTagReference.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
        }
        else
        {
            inputTagReference.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="";
        }
    }
    </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#dddddd" TEXT="#000000" LINK="#0000FF" VLINK="#800080">
    <h1 align="center">List</h1>
    <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
    <p align="center">
    <?php
        echo '<div id="checkbox-container">';

        //Create file with headers


    system("cmd /C makeit.bat");


        //Create html table
    echo '<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>';
    echo '<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>';
    echo '<table class="sortable" align="center">';

    $row = 0;
    $handle = fopen("readylist.txt", "r");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($row == 0) {
            // this is the first line of the file
            // it contains titles of columns
            $num = count($data);
            echo "<thead>\n<tr>";
            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                echo "<th align='left' height='75' width='135'>" . $data[$c] . "</th>";
            }
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "</tr>\n</thead>\n\n<tbody>";
        } else {
            // this handles the rest of the lines of the file
            $num = count($data);
            echo "<tr id=Row0$row>";
            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                echo "<td id=Col0$c>" . $data[$c] . "</td>";
            }
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='Chk$row id=Chk$row' value='Chk$row' onclick='toggle_highlight(this)'></td>";
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);

    echo "</tbody>\n</table>";



    echo '</div>';

    ?>
    </p>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

here is the code from the page that answered the persistent checkbox question, this page works for me, but the code from it on my page does not.

```
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">


    <title>CodePen - A Pen by  SitePoint</title>




        <style>
      #checkbox-container{
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

#checkbox-container div{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#checkbox-container button{
  margin-top: 5px;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: .5em .6em;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
    </style>

  </head>

  <body translate="no" >

    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something here" />

<div id="checkbox-container">
  <div>
    <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option3">
  </div>
  <button>Check All</button>
</div>

    <script src='../../jquery.js'></script>

        <script>
      var formValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formValues')) || {};
var $checkboxes = $('#checkbox-container :checkbox');
var $button = $('#checkbox-container button');
function allChecked() {
    return $checkboxes.length === $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
}
function updateButtonStatus() {
    $button.text(allChecked() ? 'Uncheck all' : 'Check all');
}
function handleButtonClick() {
    $checkboxes.prop('checked', allChecked() ? false : true);
}
function updateStorage() {
    $checkboxes.each(function () {
        formValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    });
    formValues['buttonText'] = $button.text();
    localStorage.setItem('formValues', JSON.stringify(formValues));
}
$button.on('click', function () {
    handleButtonClick();
    updateButtonStatus();
    updateStorage();
});
$checkboxes.on('change', function () {
    updateButtonStatus();
    updateStorage();
});
$.each(formValues, function (key, value) {
    $('#' + key).prop('checked', value);
});
$button.text(formValues['buttonText']);
      //# sourceURL=pen.js
    </script>



  </body>
</html>
```

Well, it's been a day, and I don't see anything here.
My assumption is that you guys are finding this just as difficult as I am.
I am still working on this and here is my logic.
I will have to get the insidehtml of one of the cells in the row as part of the onclick event, then set a cookie or use session to store the variable based on the row, and then an onload event that reads that session or cookie and checks the appropriate boxes and highlights the appropriate rows.
If anyone has any comments or suggestions, they are entirely welcome.
tia

Comment: You said yourself that you "need them to be saved, either by local storage or a cookie', so where is that code here? I don't see it... What exactly did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: i found examples using jquery and local storage, there were no errors,but the checkboxes still reset to unchecked on refresh. I'd be glad to put up all of the nonworking solutions if that will help, but I thought this would be cleaner.  I was hoping that I could add a snippet to the highlighting javascript, as that is working and is correctly fired on the checkbox selection.

Comment: You should add the code that you tried, this way you can get comments/suggestions regarding the code you already have.

Comment: I used these instructions to no avail: [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-persist-checkbox-checked-state-after-page-reload/)

Comment: I don't see any of it in your code...

Comment: I add the nonworking code.  It doesn't break the page, but neither does it retain the checkbox state.. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have a comment there "on page load", but this code doesn't really run on page load...

Comment: I ran the test code from the link, there is no onload event mentioned or in the body tag, and yet the code works

Comment: If you are using php, store the choices in a session. Then it will persist until the session is destroyed or expires.

Comment: so i've been trying some session stuff and having no luck.  Could someone kindly help me with an example?  this page is refreshing, not submitting, so I don't know how to retain the checked values,  do I add a form submit on the onclick event on the checkbox?  can the form auto submit on page unload when the auto refresh takes place?  thanks to all of you for any help.